# Git problems with ionic and subfolders

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

I have a minor git problem. The problem is that when i created a new ionic project it apparently auto initialised git as in proper "git init" (i dont remember any prompt, this is rather stupid imo?). And this whole project is in the subfolder hoursApp. And this subfolder hoursApp is in the folder appInfo, and on this upper layer i initialised git and wanted to commit and push from this upper folder(which included the folder hoursApp, readme.md and gitignore) and i did, but it didnt push the ACTUAL files of hoursApp, because apparently that was another git project and it suggested me some kind of "sub module add", but i didnt know what to do so i commited and pushed it and of course files of the actual project werent pushed (the pushed files were readme.md gitingore and folder hoursApp, which on git isnt clickable, so its content wasnt pushed).

Folder layers:
appInfo:
readme.md,
.gitignore,
hoursApp:
the actual project(ts, node modules etc...)

How do i proceed now? I just want to get the content from hoursApp pushed on git, how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want that part to be a submodule, delete the (hidden) `.git` directory in `hoursApp`.

Comment: i removed the .git and .gitignore and its still not pushing it up. It only pushed the dummy text filed from the folder on the upper layer appInfo. Should i maybe copy everything to the upper folder and install all necessary modules there(basically like copying the whole project).

Comment: Did you `git add hoursApp` after removing `hoursApp`'s `.git`?

Comment: I thought git add . will take care of that. Nonetheless i did git add hoursApp now and commited and it said "Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean" .

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by copying the project from the subfolder to other folder(i didnt copy node modules, they were like 1gb). And then npm installed mode nodules so the project was runnable. Inited git in the new folder and pushed from there. It worked.

Apparently once you make a subfolder an explicit module/sub git project you cant undo it, thats why i wasnt able to push it on, even after deleting its .git files.

Comment: Oh, you already had made it a submodule? That can be undone by deleting the `[submodule "foo"]` sections from `.git/config`

Comment: That appears to be the solution. Tested it on a dummy file i created. Tyvm.